# Continuous results from a single function call

Tags: python, function, while-loop

I am extremely new to Python, and to programming in general, so I decided to write some basic code to help me learn the ins and outs of it. I decided to try making a database editor, and have developed the following code:

```
name = [] 
rank = [] 
age = []
cmd = input("Please enter a command: ")

def recall(item):   #Prints all of the information for an individual when given his/her name
    if item in name:
        index = name.index(item)    #Finds the position of the given name
        print(name[index] + ", " + rank[index] + ", " + age[index])     #prints the element of every list with the position of the name used as input
else:
    print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid input.")

def operation(cmd):
    while cmd != "end":
        if cmd == "recall":
            print(name)
            item = input("Please enter an input: ")
            recall(item)
        elif cmd == "add":
            new_name = input("Please enter a new name: ")
            name.append(new_name)
            new_rank = input("Please enter a new rank: ")
            rank.append(new_rank)
            new_age = input("Please input new age: ")
            age.append(new_age)
            recall(new_name)
        else:
            print("Please input a valid command.")
    else:
        input("Press enter to quit.")

operation(cmd)
```

I want to be able to call `operation(cmd)`, and from it be able to call as many functions/perform as many actions as I want. Unfortunately, it just infinitely prints one of the outcomes instead of letting me put in multiple commands.

How can I change this function so that I can call `operation(cmd)` once, and call the other functions repeatedly? Or is there a better way to go about doing this? Please keep in mind I am a beginner and just trying to learn, not a developer.

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone who answered! I finally found the problem. All I had to do is add `cmd = input("Please enter new command: ")` at the end of the `if` and `elif` statements, and add a return at the end of each function. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at your code:

```
 while cmd != "end":
    if cmd == "recall":
```

If you call `operation` with anything than "end", "recall" or "add", the condition within `while` is `True`, the next `if`  is also `True`,  but the subsequent `if`s are false. Therefore, the function executes the following block

```
else:
    print("Please input a valid command.")
```

and the `while` loop continues to its next lap. Since `cmd` hasn't changed, the same process continues over and over again.

Comment: That makes sense... But how can I fix that? How can I change my code to do what I want it to do?

Comment: For example you can `return` after the ` print("Please input a valid command.")`

Comment: Thank you! Now it repeats correctly, but only within the individual `if` and `elif` statements. I think the problem is that the function still reads the same value for `cmd` within the individual parts of the function. I'll play around with the code and see if I get any results.

Answer (score 0):

You have not put anything in your code to show where operator_1, operator_2, and operator_3 come from, though you have hinted that operator_3 comes from the commandline.

You need to have some code to get the next value for "operator_3". This might be from a list of parameters to function_3, in which case you would get:

```
def function_3(operator_3):
    for loopvariable in operator_3:
       if loopvariable == some_value_1:
#(and so forth, then:)

function_3(["this","that","something","something else"])
```

Or, you might get it from input (by default, the keyboard):

```
def function_3():
    read_from_keyboard=raw_input("First command:")
    while (read_from_keyboard != "end"):
       if read_from_keyboard == some_value_1:
 #(and so forth, then at the end of your while loop, read the next line)
       read_from_keyboard = raw_input("Next command:")
```

Comment: I don't follow, but that is probably by my own folly. I presented my code badly. Sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you only check `operator_3` once in `function_3`, the second time you ask the user for an operator, you don't store its value, which is why its only running with one condition.

```
def function_3(operator_3):
    while operator_3 != "end":
        if operator_3 == some_value_1
            function_1(operator_1)
        elif operator_3 == some_value_2
            function_2
        else:
            print("Enter valid operator.")  # Here, the value of the input is lost
```

The logic you are trying to implement is the following:

1. Ask the user for some input.
2. Call `function_3` with this input.
3. If the input is not `end`, run either `function_1` or `function_2`.
4. Start again from step 1

However, you are missing #4 above, where you are trying to restart the loop again.

To fix this, make sure you store the value entered by the user when you prompt them for an operator. To do that, use the `input` function if you are using Python3, or `raw_input` if you are using Python2. These functions prompt the user for some input and then return that input to your program:

```
def function_3(operator_3):
   while operator_3 != 'end':
      if operator_3 == some_value_1:
          function_1(operator_3)
      elif operator_3 == some_value_2:
          function_2(operator_3)
      else:
          operator_3 = input('Enter valid operator: ')
      operator_3 = input('Enter operator or "end" to quit: ')
```

Comment: I think you understood the logic I was going by, but I'm not sure I follow yours. I think I presented my code badly. I rewrote the question to be more specific, so hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are trying to get input from the user, but you never implemented it in function_3...

```
def function_3(from_user):
    while (from_user != "end"):
        from_user = raw_input("enter a command: ")
        if from_user == some_value_1:
        # etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, but I think that was my fault. I presented my code in a highly abstract, probably incorrect way. I have updated my question with the actual code I'm working with.